# Low-level caching doesn't work in development, even after running rails dev:cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I'm trying to get [Rails low-level caching](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching) working in my local development environment. I ran [`rails dev:cache`](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#caching-in-development), which created the `tmp/caching-dev.txt` file as expected. And my `config/environments/develpoment.rb` file contains the code that checks for the existence of that file and turns on caching if it's present. But the cache isn't being used when I run my app.

Even when I modify my `development.rb` file directly to set `config.cache_store = :memory_store` regardless of whether `tmp/caching-dev.txt` is present, low-level caching still does not work!

What else am I missing to get caching working in development?

Comment: Can you please share your development config code where you check for the existence of tmp/caching-dev.txt

Comment: @MarkMerritt It's the same as the default generated config file described in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/24470#issuecomment-207546888